# why does the i2cdetect always gives UU on my RTC in embedded Linux

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, i2c

I'd like to communicate read from my RTC in C code rather than the `"hwclock"` shell command.

However, when I use `i2cdetect`, it shows `0x68`(which is my RTC slave address) is  having the status `"UU"`, which means "Probing was skipped, because this address is currently in use by a driver". And after I tried the `i2cget`, its givng "could bot set address to `0x68`: Device or resource busy".

So I'm thinking if there are some problem in my Linux kernel that will force to read from my RTC all the time, or some other reason.

Thanks

Comment: whats the output of `lsmod`?

Answer (score 13):

I am assuming that you are using DS-1307 RTC, or one of its variants (because of 0x68 slave address). Check if its driver is loaded by:

```
$ lsmod | grep rtc
```

If you seen an entry of rtc_ds1307, (like this -> `rtc_ds1307  17394  0` ) in the output of above command then this driver might be in hold of that address.

If the driver is loaded in system then unload it using

```
$ rmmod rtc-ds1307
```

EDIT:

(In light of OP's feedback,) Please do the following

1) `cat /sys/bus/i2c/devices/3-0068/modalias`. This will give you the name of the kernel driver that is keeping this device busy. Copy the driver-name after the colon(:)
OP's output of the command tells us that its **ds1337**

2) Check if ds1337 is an alias for a driver, using

```
grep ds1337 /lib/modules/`uname -r`/modules.alias
```

Hopefully you will get the following output

```
alias i2c:ds1337 rtc_ds1307
```

This confirms our presumption that rtc_ds1307 is infact the driver in hold of the I2C address 0x68.

3) use `rmmod rtc_ds1307` to unload the driver.
Note: This will only work if the driver is a Loadable Kernel Module, otherwise you will see the following error:

```
ERROR: Module rtc_ds1307 does not exist in /proc/modules
```

In that case you will have to recompile the kernel again with that driver disabled/modularized.

Comment: hmm.. can u give us the output of `ls /sys/bus/i2c/devices`

Comment: The ls command gives 3-0068(3 is the bus number), and some other devices. And btw, I can read from the RTC using ioctl() function from my C code.  Which is weird since i2ctools cannot read.

Comment: The cat command gives me i2c:ds1337 
and then I run command 'rmmod ds1337' or 'rmmod -f ds1337', but it gives out: cannot unload 'ds1337', unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter.

Comment: okay.. ds1337 might be an alias for a module.
Try

`grep ds1337 /lib/modules/\`uname -r\`/modules.alias`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34159/discussion-between-micromolvi-and-henryyao)

Answer (score 0):

0x68 is being used by some driver,
 Disable that driver in kernel source code and recompile source code.